# Search backslach in tcl using regexp

Tags: tcl, regexp-replace

How to search backslash "\" in tcl using regexp. I tried following

```
regexp {\\} "b\a"
regexp {\\\\} "b\a"
```

I want to search text between "." and "\.". How to do this? Eg:
abcd.efg\.hij => efg , for this I tried this:

```
regexp {\.[a-z]*\\.} "abcd.efg\.hij" X
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When single backslash is used in double quotes, then it has no special meaning at all. It should be escaped.

```
% set input "abcd.efg\.hij"; # Check the return value, it does not have backslash in it
abcd.efg.hij
%
% set user "din\esh"; # Check the return value
dinesh
%
% set input "abcd.efg\\.hij"; # Escaped the backslash. Check the return value
abcd.efg\.hij
%
% set input {abcd.efg\.hij}; # Or you have to brace the string
abcd.efg\.hij
%
```

So, your regexp should be updated as ,

```
% regexp "\\\\" "b\\a"
1
% regexp {\\} "b\\a"
1
% regexp {\\} {b\a}
1
% regexp {\\} {b\\a}
1
%
```

To extract the required data,

```
% set input {abcd.efg\.hij}
abcd.efg\.hij
%  regexp {\.(.*)?\\} $input ignore match
1
% set match
efg
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `\.([^\\\.]+)\\\.` but it depends on what other possible samples may be.

The pattern matches an escaped dot `\.`, then parenthesized expression `([^\\\.]+)` that will extract `efg` (it says: not `[^` backslash `\\` or dot `\.` one or more times `]+`), then explicit backslash `\\` and dot `\.`.

Your pattern will also work if you'll use capturing parenthesized expression. The match captured by such an expression will be put into the second variable:

```
regexp {\.([a-z]*)\\.} {abcd.efg\.hij} matchVar subMatchVar
```

You also have to take into account that a backslash in double-quoted string `"abcd.efg\.hij"` is substituted by the interpreter - the final string will become `abcd.efg.hij`, effectively preventing your pattern from recognizing it. So here I used curly braces or might use a variable with that string.

---

Take a look at [Visual REGEXP](http://laurent.riesterer.free.fr/regexp/). I use it occasionally.